# python parsing file for having common word and print next line

Tags: python

I am trying to parse a text file where if it contains,words like "car,bike,automobile" ,if these words (possibly it will be more than 3)exists then it has to print as "runs on fuel" and next line

Program:
its giving me errors

```
with open(qwer.txt) as f:
vehicle=("car","bike","automobile")            
   for line in f:
      for part in line.split():
            if vehicle in part:
                 print line.index(key)+1
                 print "runs on fuel"
```

please help answer appreciated!

Comment: Change `vehicle in part` to `part in vehicle`.

Comment: but in same line if i have  like "car and bike" it has to be printed as "runs on fuel runs on fuel" instead it prints only one time "runs on fuel".please help!

Answer (score 0):

sets are best for this type of thing

```
with open("qwer.txt") as f:
    vehicle=set(("car","bike","automobile"))
    for line in f:
      match = vehicle.intersection(line.split())
      if match:
            print "%s runs on fuel" % match.pop()
```